# Singularity of $B$-field in a Dirac String

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, dirac-delta-distributions, magnetic-monopoles, dirac-string

I was assigned this question related to Dirac strings:

> Given a vector potential  $\vec{A}= \frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{r\sin(\theta)}\hat{\phi}$, show that there is a singularity in the $B$ field proportional to $\Theta(-z)\delta(x)\delta(y)$ on the $z$ axis. ($\Theta(x-x_0)$ is the step function with its jump at $x_0$) Find the proportionality constant.

My attempt at a solution:

So showing there is a singularity simply results from the fact that at $\theta=0$, the vector potential explodes because the denominator goes to zero. The same holds true for $r$. My question becomes quantifying the magnitude of this singularity via this proportionality constant. I'm assuming it's essentially a measure of how quickly the field increases close the the $z$ axis, but I'm not sure how to procede from here. I've looked at quite a bit of literature on the matter, including Dirac's original paper, but they all simply state there is a singularity, and make no statement about the size of it. Any insight that can be offered about the nature of this singularity would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: Careful: at $\theta=0$ the _numerator_ also goes to zero, so it's not immediately obvious that it should blow up there.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:  integrate $\vec{A}$ around a small loop of size $\epsilon$ centered along the $z$-axis.  Use the fact that the magnetic flux through this loop is $\Phi_B = \oint \vec{A} \cdot d \vec{l}$.